# How to prove that $\sum _{n=2}^{\infty }\:\frac{\cos\left(\log\left(\log n\right)\right)}{\log n}$ diverges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Well, I used symbolab and they said it diverges, but I don't like their explanation. (it's a long answer why I don't "like" it,better not to write that)

Comment: $\ln \ln n \in (a,a+b)$ for $n \in (e^{e^a}, e^{e^{a+b}})$. taking $a = 2 k \pi, b = 2k\pi + \pi/4$ you have $$\sum_{n= e^{e^{2k\pi}}}^{e^{e^{2k\pi+\pi/4}}} \frac{\cos(\ln \ln n)}{\ln n} > \cos(\pi / 4)\sum_{n= e^{e^{2k\pi}}}^{e^{e^{2k\pi+\pi/4}}} \frac{1}{\ln e^{e^{2k\pi+\pi/4}}} > \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2 e^{2k\pi+\pi/4}}(e^{e^{2k\pi+\pi/4}}-e^{e^{2k\pi}})$$ that is unbounded when $k \to \infty$

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if partial sums will accumulate on both + and - infinity.
For given $k$ (large) you may look at what n-values verify
$$ \log(\log(n)) \in [(k-1/4)\pi, (k+1/4)\pi]$$
(where $(-1)^k \cos \geq 1/\sqrt{2}$).  The contribution from those $n$ values will diverge with $k$