# Does $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\cos\ln\ln n}{\ln n}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\cos\ln\ln n}{\ln n}$$
My idea is
$$-\frac1{\ln n}\le\frac{\cos\ln\ln n}{\ln n}\le\frac1{\ln n}$$
But I don't know if $\sum\frac1{\ln n}$ converges.

Comment: $\sum\frac1{\ln{n}}$ diverges !

Comment: Then i got nothing.

Comment: I am so sorry, my series start with 2, i will correct it

Comment: This already has an answer here (kind of): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1914685/how-to-prove-that-sum-n-2-infty-frac-cos-left-log-left-log-n-right

Comment: Unfreaking belivable thats a girl from my college.

Comment: You mean there are real people using this website !??

Answer (score 1):

The first term in the [Euler-Macluarin Summation Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#The_formula) is

$$\int_1^N \frac{\cos(\log\log x)}{\log(x)}\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\log\log N} e^{e^x}\cos(x)\,dx$$

which diverges as $N\to \infty$.  Therefore, the series of interest diverges.

Comment: Rush, please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head and from my phone:

Cos(log log n)
Is essentially constant for longer and longer stretches
and sum 1/log n diverges so the sum diverges.

I'm sure this could be made rigorous for any function thst grows slowly like log log.